# Is there a way to grab dependencies when running groovy script with groovy-all-*.jar?

Tags: java, groovy, ivy, groovy-grape

I am trying to run a groovy script like:

```
java -jar %JAVA_HOME%\..\lib\groovy-all-2.1.7.jar hello.groovy.
```

The problem is, I am grabbing dependencies in the beggining of the script like:

```
@Grapes([
      @Grab("org.apache.poi:poi:3.11"),
])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: IMHO your call should be done using groovy, not java. Like this `groovy hello.groovy`

Comment: I have to do it using the groovy-all jar.